# Eliminate QWebChannel property notifier signal warnings

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qwebengineview, qtwebchannel

I'm using `QWebEngineView` with `QWebChannel`, similar to this:

```
class AppView(QWebEngineView):
    def __init__(self):
        QWebEngineView.__init__(self)
        self.ch = QWebChannel(self.page())
        self.page().setWebChannel(self.ch)
```

Then I call:

```
self.ch.registerObject('app',self)
```

and everything runs correctly. However, I then get log-spam like this:

> ...
>   Property 'title'' of object 'AppView' has no notify signal and is not constant, value updates in HTML will be broken!
>   Property 'url'' of object 'AppView' has no notify signal and is not constant, value updates in HTML will be broken!
>   Property 'selectedText'' of object 'AppView' has no notify signal and is not constant, value updates in HTML will be broken!
>   Property 'hasSelection'' of object 'AppView' has no notify signal and is not constant, value updates in HTML will be broken!
>   Property 'zoomFactor'' of object 'AppView' has no notify signal and is not constant, value updates in HTML will be broken!
>   ...

These seem to be the properties of the derived `QWebEngineView` class that have been pulled in. Is there a way to correctly derive this, or does the whole structure need to change so that I'm not pulling in `QWebEngineView`?

`AppView` has other signals and slots needed in the JS code.

Comment: One solution is simply to avoid registering objects with properties which have no notifier signal (e.g. use a delegate that subclasses `QObject`). That may be inconvenient in many cases, though. So it may be preferable to [install a message handler](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtglobal.html#qInstallMessageHandler) and just filter out all the log spam at source.

Answer (score 1):

Disable all qt warnings:

```
QtCore.qInstallMessageHandler(lambda x,y,z: None)
```

Feed your custom handler-function inside for detail filtration